# cython exception ignored while having return type as void* (void pointer)

Tags: cython

I have the below program where c code is calling python function via cython and i want a exception to be raised/caught if python returns anything other than `ctypes.Structure`

C code

```
$ cat main.c
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t subtype;
    uint8_t action;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) c_data;

int
main()
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("caller", initcaller);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("caller");

        const char* str = get_data_frm_python(2);
        printf("Printing in C returing str - %s\n", str);

        c_data* reqP = (c_data*)get_data_frm_python(1);
        if (reqP)
                printf("Printing in C returing struct - %u, %u, %u\n", reqP->type, reqP->subtype, reqP->action);

    return 0;
}
```

cython interface

```
$ cat caller.pyx
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '')

from ctypes import addressof, Structure
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t
from c_struct import get_message

cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *:
    data = get_message(typ)

    if not isinstance(data, Structure):
        print "Raising an exception"
        raise ValueError("get_message MUST return object of ctypes.Structure")

    cdef uintptr_t ptr = <uintptr_t>(addressof(data))
    return <const void*>(ptr)
```

Python code

```
$ cat c_struct.py
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from ctypes import *

class Request(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
            ('type', c_ubyte),
            ('subtype', c_ubyte),
            ('action', c_ubyte),
            ]

req_msg = Request()
some_string = "String object From Python"
def get_message(typ):
    if typ == 1:
        req_msg.type = 12
        req_msg.subtype = 2
        req_msg.action = 3
        return req_msg
    else:
        return "String object From Python"
```

Makefile for reference

```
$ cat Makefile

target = main
cy_interface = caller

CY := cython  --gdb
PYTHONINC := $(shell python-config --includes)
CFLAGS := -Wall $(PYTHONINC) -fPIC -O0 -ggdb3
LDFLAGS := $(shell python-config --ldflags)

CC=gcc

all: $(target)

.PRECIOUS: caller.c

%.c: %.pyx
        $(CY) $+

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -fPIC $(CFLAGS) -c $+

$(target): $(cy_interface).o $(target).o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm -rf caller.o caller.c caller.h $(target).o $(target)
        rm -rf __pycache__ *.pyc
```

Finally the output

```
$ ./main
Raising an exception
Printing in C returing str - (null)
Printing in C returing struct - 12, 2, 3
```

If i remove `except *` from cython interface, i get the below output

```
cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ):
    data = get_message(typ)
...

$ ./main
Raising an exception
ValueError: get_message MUST return object of ctypes.Structure
Exception ValueError: ValueError('get_message MUST return object of ctypes.Structure',) in 'caller.get_data_frm_python' ignored
Printing in C returing str - (null)
Printing in C returing struct - 12, 2, 3
```

Can someone please help me on what should i do to terminate the c program whenever an exception is raised
in cython interface

Comment: You'll note that `cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ):` __does not match__ the line in your code `cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *:`. I suggest you need to recompile the module. Voting to close as "typo/can't be reproduced"

Comment: DavidW - Sorry i did not understand what u r saying.. are u saying that after changing to cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *: i did not recompile ? I have makefile where i clean and build everytime i make changes to either cython/c file Added makefile for reference. If u could please try out the above program locally then u should also reproduce the issue.

Comment: I don't quite know. However the code in your traceback doesn't match the code in the question which suggests something hasn't been updated on your end.

Comment: So according to u.. what should be the behaviour ? whenever cython raises an exception c code would report and stop or report and ignore or don't report anything ? In my case as i mentioned no error's are reported with `cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *:`

Comment: With `cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *` (or possibly better `cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except NULL`?) you should be able to catch the `ValueError` as normal. It should not say "ignored"

Comment: :( i just tried this same result. i.e no errors are reproted

Comment: Ah - actually I think I understand the problem. You do want `except NULL` (so Cython knows what to return when you raise an exception). Since you're calling it from C you need to check if it's returned `NULL` then query the Python error code (`PyErr_Occurred()`). If you were calling from Cython this would happen automatically. I'll write a proper answer later when I have time (if no-one else has done so first)

Comment: Thanks @DavidW, i will be waiting for your official answer.. but i have one more query is there no way i can raise an exception and terminate the program from cython ? i mean my whole intention is if python returns anything other than ctypes.structure there should be an error and termination

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think it's strictly required, but it's generally a good idea to tell Cython what the "error return value" should be (e.g. `except NULL`). If `NULL` can also sometimes be returned as a valid value then use `except NULL?`.

If the function is called from Cython then it will automatically check for errors when the function finishes. However you're calling it from C so you must do so yourself. The [Python documentation gives useful functions for probing the error state](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html).

Putting this together into a simple minimal example (i.e. cut down from your rather extensive and incomplete example) gives:

```
# caller.pyx

cdef int i = 1;

cdef public const void* get_data_frm_python(int typ) except *:
    if typ:
        raise ValueError("get_message MUST return object of ctypes.Structure")

    return &i
```

and

```
// main.c
#include <Python.h>
#include "caller.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("caller", PyInit_caller); // initcaller in Python 2
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_ImportModule("caller");

    const void* reqP = get_data_frm_python(1);
    if (reqP) {
        printf("Printing in C returing struct - %p\n", reqP);
    } else {
        if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
            PyErr_Print();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

If you *really* want to have Cython quit on error (rather than propagating an exception) then just using the Python builtin `exit()` function seems to work.
Obviously in this case you wouldn't raise a Python exception - you'd just print an error message and call `exit`. This seems like a bad design to me though.